# How to echo "Hello World" in civicrm?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, php, hooks, civicrm-home

I need to echo "hello world" in civicrm how to do this in any page in civicrm? i'm trying to do this using hooks_civicrm_post but there is no result.

Answer (score 2):

The civicrm_post hook performs stuff after a database update, and does not necessarily just echo stuff on a page.

If you want to customize CiviCRM I strongly recommend you read the [Developer Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/) carefully, and possibly check if you can follow a CiviCRM developer training somewhere.

I assume you do not actually really want to echo "hello world" on any page, so perhaps it will help if you tell us what you really want to do?

Comment: i know that civicrm_post hook performs after a database update, but i need to echo something using hooks_civicrm_post after creating individual contact. when trying to echo anything there is no result.

Comment: You can not simply echo something, what you could do is use the status messages? So something like CRM_Core_Session::setStatus(ts('Hello World', 'I am awake', 'success');

Comment: ok but if i need to add some code where should i put it?

Comment: Depends at what moment you want this to happen, and I really do think you need to study CiviCRM customization and invest some time. I get the feeling from your questions you are going to do something without understanding the basics :-)

Comment: thanks, so where should i start?

Comment: Probably the Developer Guide as mentioned before: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/